# How to perform MSCK REPAIR TABLE to load only specific partitions

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have data in AWS S3 for more than 2 months that is partitioned and stored by `day`. I want to start using the data using the external table that I created.

Currently I see only a couple of partitions and I want to make sure my metadata picks up all the partitions. I tried using `msck repair table tablename` using `hive` after logging in to EMR Cluster's master node. However, may be due to data volume, it is taking a lot of time to execute that command.

Can I do msck repair table so that I can load only a specific day? does `msck` allow to load specific partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD [IF NOT EXISTS] PARTITION partition_spec [LOCATION 'location'][, PARTITION partition_spec [LOCATION 'location'], ...];
```

...as described in [Hive DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddPartitions) doc.